# excessive memory usage in multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, performance-testing, python-multiprocessing

I have a code using python multiprocessing pool. But it is using excessive memory. I have tested both pool.map and pool.imap_unordered, however, both using the same amount of memory. Below is a simplified version of my code.

```
    import random, time, multiprocessing
    def func(arg):
       y = arg**arg  # Don't look into here because my original function is 
                     # much complicated and I can't change anything here. 
       print y


    p     = multiprocessing.Pool(24)
    count = 0
    start = time.time()
    for res in p.imap_unordered(func, range(48000), chunksize=2):
    #for res in p.map(func, range(48000), chunksize=2):
       print "[%5.2f] res:%s  count:%s"%(time.time()-start, res, count)
       count += 1
```

The function saves output in the files and doesn't have any return statement. The above code took:
p.map: CPU Utilized: 03:18:31, Job Wall-clock time: 00:08:17, Memory Utilized: 162.92 MB
p.imap_unordered: CPU Utilized: 04:00:13, Job Wall-clock time: 00:10:02, Memory Utilized: 161.16 MB

I have total 128GB of memory and my original code stops due to memory exceed. Both map and imap_unordered shows the same problem. I was expecting imap_unordered to take much less memory. What should I modify to have less memory consumption without changing the func (the original one)?

Comment: How are you measuring memory consumption? If your code is actually your real code, the memory involved in your actual processing is trivial; the real memory cost is the 25 Python interpreters you end up running. The maximum resident set size for a single interpreter doing basically nothing (I do nothing but import `resource` and call `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)`) on my system is ~7.5 MB, which for 25 processes would already exceed 161 MB of peak memory usage. 161 MB is nothing for a high level language.

Comment: I am using sbatch to submit my job and when the job is finished the output file gives the memory usage. I also used sacct to find out the total memory usage. I have total 128GB of memory and my original code stops due to memory exceed. Both map and imap_unordered shows the same problem.

Comment: @unutbu: the above example function is just for testing which method takes less memory. Anyway, the above code takes only 161 MB. My question is why p.map and imap_unordered take similar memory. I can not change my original function, so don't look into func. Is there any way to reduce memory consumption without changing the func?

Comment: The main difference between `p.map` and `p.imap_unordered` is in the type of object returned. They both queue up all the tasks immediately, so I don't think there is going to any significant difference in the amount of memory they use.

Comment: @unutbu: Computing `47999 ** 47999` is actually pretty trivial for Python. Yes, the number is huge, but it's representable in log2 bits of the actual value; the memory used for `47999 ** 47999` is around 97 KB. Even if all the `arg**arg` values had to exist in memory at once (they shouldn't, since the workers compute them and discard them per task), the memory overhead for them (on 64 bit CPython 2.7) would be around 2.15 GB; non-trivial, but if the machine has 128 GB of RAM this should be fine (assuming they're running a 64 bit build of Python, so they can actually use all the RAM).

Comment: @SUV: Can you provide more details of your setup? And the complete traceback as well, if Python produces one (an important part of any Python [MCVE]). My immediate thought is that perhaps you're running a 32 bit build of Python, so something you're doing in a worker is trying to allocate >2 GB of memory in one large block, and it dies on the failed allocation (which wouldn't show up in your memory usage stats because the allocation was never actually performed). That's just one of many guesses though; a true [MCVE] is probably the only way to answer this for sure.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You are absolutely right -- `47999 ** 47999` is not a problem.

Comment: @SUV: You might be getting a `Exceeded job memory limit` error because SLURM imposes a [100MB memory limit per node by default](https://www.rc.fas.harvard.edu/resources/documentation/slurm-memory/). Try setting a larger memory limit: `SBATCH --mem 200`.